# Calculations in php code do not take place

Tags: javascript

This is part of my code but calculations not work
I want amt=qty*rate after entry/change in qty or rate field amount should be calculated

```
                    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                    function calcamt()
                        {   
                        var a = document.getElementById('txtqty').value;
                        var b = document.getElementById('txtrate').value;
                        document.getElementById('pamt').value=a*b;
                        }
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
                    function calcvtaxamt() 
                        {   
                        var a = document.getElementById('txtamt').value;
                        var b = document.getElementById('txtvtaxperc').value;
                        document.getElementById('pvtaxamt').value=round(a*b*0.01,0);
                        }
                    </script>
                   <td align="right"><input type="text" maxlength="10" size="10" name="txtqty"  onkeyup="javascript:calcamt()" value="<?php echo $pqty; ?>"/>
                   <td align="right"><input type="text" maxlength="10" size="10" name="txtrate" onkeyup="javascript:calcamt()" value="<?php echo $prate; ?>"/>
                   <td align="right"><input type="text" maxlength="12" size="12" name="txtamt" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $pamt; ?>"/>
```

Comment: You haven't assigned IDs to your input fields. An `id` is not the same as a `name`

Answer (score -1):

You have to give class to your qty and rate. Also remove function onkeyup. Like below,

```
<input type="text" class="qty" maxlength="10" size="10" name="txtqty" value="<?php echo $pqty; ?>"/>
<input type="text" class="rate" maxlength="10" size="10" name="txtrate" value="<?php echo $prate; ?>"/>

Then in javascript:

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".qty, .rate" ).live('change',function() {
        calcamt();
    });
});
</script>

Also put your rest of javascript code to calculate amt.
```

Comment: If any more questions just post it.

Comment: The OP hasn't tagged or suggested jQuery. Instead of answering the OPs question you've completely rewritten a simple piece of code and used a deprecated API.